# Error : object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

Подскажите почему при загрузке json из файла я получаю данную ошибку?Может есть способ отдебажить это?

Вот классы если понадобится

```
#Server
public class Server
{
     public static Dictionary<string, Users> PlayerDictionary = new 
     Dictionary<string, Users>();       
}

#Bootstrap
public class Bootstrap : Facepunch.MonoBehaviour
    {
        public void Awake()
        {
            {
                if (File.Exists(server.datadir + "users.json"))
                {
                    Server.PlayerDictionary = JsonHelper.GetInstance.ReadyFile<Dictionary<string, Users>>("users.json");
                }
        }
    }

#Users
public class Users
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public PlayerClient Client { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Server.UsersFlags Flags { get; set; }

        public string Vkurl { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public Users(PlayerClient client)
        {
            Client = client;
            Username = client.netUser.displayName;
        }
    }

#JsonHelper
public T ReadyFile<T>(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                return File.Exists(server.datadir + path)
                    ? Deserialize<T>(File.ReadAllText(server.datadir + path))
                    : default(T);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error saveFile: " + ex.Message);
                return default(T);
            }
        }
```

Cам json

{
  "76561197962496109": {
    "Vkurl": "URL",
    "Username": "Kostia"
  }
}

```
public static T ReadyFile<T>(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                return File.Exists(server.datadir + path) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(server.datadir + path)) : default(T);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error saveFile: " + ex.);
                return default(T);
            }

        }
```

Comment: __Может есть способ отдебажить это?__ На какой строке у вас исключение возникает, вы самостоятельно дебажили?

Comment: А сам json чтож не предоставили?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov на строке Server.PlayerDictionary = JsonHelper.GetInstance.ReadyFile<Dictionary<string, Users>>("users.json");

Comment: @Костя: (1) Если падает внутри `JsonHelper`, дайте его код. (2) Внесите информацию об ошибке в вопрос.

Comment: @VladD добавил.

Comment: @Костя: Ну, а где GetInstance? На нём же падает.

Comment: @VladD GetInstance это создание class если его нету в переменной public static JsonHelper jh;

Comment: @Костя: Поскольку вы не знаете, где именно ошибка, то лучше дайте весь релевантный код. А лучше [mcve].

Comment: @VladD я кажется понял - он не может object перевести в Users после того,как файл появился

Comment: @VladD но не знаю почему